# Rails has_many :through with JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, has-many-through

i have a place model like this:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :typologies, :through => :typology_places
  has_many :typology_places, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

typologies model:

```
class Typology < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :places, :through => :typology_places
  has_many :typology_places, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

and typology_places model

```
class TypologyPlace < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :typology
  belongs_to :place
end
```

I want update a place by Reast API JSON and so i send this body:

```
{
    "place": {
        "typology_ids": [1,2]
     }
}
```

but i have this error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: typology_ids:

With post it works...any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Controller:

```
def update
    response = Place.where(['id = ? and user_id = ?', params[:id], current_user.id])

    if response.update_all(place_params)
      render :json => {
        :status => :ok,
        :result => response
      }.to_json
    else
      render json: response.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

private
    def place_params
      params.require(:place).permit(:user_id, :name, :description, :image, :opendate, :latitude, :longitude, :street, :housenumber, :city, :country, :vat, :typology_ids => [], :cooking_ids => [], :like_ids => [], :paytype_ids => [], :service_ids => [])
    end
```

Comment: What are you doing with the `typology_ids`? None of your tables will have a column with that (`TypologyPlace` will have a `typology_id`) so that error doesn't tell us much

Comment: Only with UPDATE call not works...

Comment: can you post that controller action?

Comment: @Rocco, i have updated

Comment: what line does it fail on? if it's this one `if response.update_all(place_params)` it may be that you need to have an `  accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the Place model ([docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)). If you can't figure that out then please post the working controller action and the full params hash and I'll try to spot the difference

Comment: Yes, it fail on `if response.update_all(place_params)`. My request is like this => `{"place"=>{"typology_ids"=>[1]},"format"=>:json,"id"=>"5"}`. See the update for the place_params.